# Can the fun argument of scripy.optimize.root be longer than the x0 argument?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

I am solving a non linear partial differential equation in python and I am using scripy.optimize.root. My initial guess x0 has a length of N and my function that I want to optimize has a length N+1 because of a specific boundary condition at the top. I keep getting there error: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'function_to_optimize'.Shape should be (150,) but it is (151,). Is there a way to use optimize.root where the fun argument is longer than the x0 argument?

I wanted to try adding an additional node at the top of x0 so that the dimensions match but that would require a lot of rewriting of my model functions and it would be easier if I did not have to do that.

Comment: Why is it difficult to add another element to x0? It's just `x0 = np.append(x0, 0)`, no? It seems like this would be simplest.

Comment: lots of slicing on functions within the model that would have to be changed. Not difficult but just a bit time consuming and it would make more sense if there were a way to define x0 and fun to be different lengths.

Comment: Why would you need to make lots of other changes? I get that you're using slicing, but why does that complicate it? It seems like this is a one line change affecting one variable.

Comment: Usually with these functions `x0` determines the number variables it varies to optimize the fit.  I.e the size of the result.  Often `fun` is supposed return a scalar (for minimize) or array of `x0` size.  That may vary with the solution method.  Some methods also take separate boundary and  constraint arguments (functions).

Comment: you should show the actual `root` call and error traceback. We shouldn't be guessing

Comment: I may have found the function that is checking the `function` return value shape, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/c1ed5ece8ffbf05356a22a8106affcd11bd3aee0/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L184.  The full error traceback should confirm whether my sleuthing was right or not.

Comment: Look at `def _check_fun` at line 24

Comment: Thanks all I have figured it out. @NickODell was correct and it was very easy to add another element.

Comment: If this question is solved then you should mark it as closed